# Turning on Front and Back Flashlight at same time

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, flashlight

I am working on an Android app that can turns on both Front & Back flashlight at the same time. The app works on some phone (mine, Moto Z Play) but doesn't seem to work on many others (Samsung Galaxy J5, Moto Z2 Play, etc).

When the user turns on one flashlight, it turns on, but as soon as he turns on another flashlight, the previous on turns on and the one turned on this time lights up.

I am using the Camera2 API. I think its some sort of hardware restriction (just a guess) that is not allowing both flashlights to turn on at the same time.
Is there any way that I can turn on both flashlights at the same time on all devices?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is "no". It is too short to qualify as a good answer, though.